# The easiest Junit test for connection to database in spring boot application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, junit

I started to write application with friend and I would like to write a simple test for database connection. He is owner of server so test will be red now of course but when he set up database and change url, password and username it should become green. I think if there is some simpler test than writing controller/service/repository and try to do some operation on it to check database connection.
All we have for now is spring boot app generated by spring initilizr and application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=dummy_url
spring.datasource.username=dummy_username
spring.datasource.password=dummy_pass
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Is it testable in this state or I must create fully operational endpoint and test it?

Comment: When you create a project that use Spring Boot you should have a test class that look like this:

    @ SpringBootTest
    class YOUR_APPLICATION_NAMEApplicationTests {

  @ Test
  void contextLoads() {}
    }

If the contextLoads test pass your db connection is ok.

Comment: @AM13, not really, it works always, even when I use `wrongusername` in application.properties

I was just thinking about some shot to db and check response something like healthcheck

Answer (score 2):

try looking into JHipster: https://www.jhipster.tech/

normally you can use a memory database like h2 for local and test environment ;)

Comment: thanks for jhipster, I'll look at it. Yes, true, I know H2 database however it must be postgreSQL this time